# The server.port property of a Spring Boot web application is ignored by Docker Engine on Windows

Tags: java, windows, spring-boot, docker, tomcat

**TL;DR**

The `server.port` property defined in a *Spring Boot* application.properties file is not getting honored by the Docker engine when running a web application in Tomcat.

---

**Background :**

I have a simple Spring Boot application containing a single rest endpoint. I am able to run this application in Eclipse and access the rest endpoint successfully from the browser.

However, when I try to deploy the same application in a Docker container, I am unable to access the rest endpoint from the browser.

**Dockerfile :**

```
FROM tomcat
EXPOSE 8000
RUN rm -rf /user/local/tomcat/webapps/*
COPY ./target/my-web-app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

**Spring Boot application.properties :**

```
spring.application.name=my-web-app
server.port=8000
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

**Docker images output :**

```
CK@Ping MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker images
REPOSITORY           TAG                  IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
myrepo/my-web-app    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT       625e9d889139        4 minutes ago       694MB
```

**Start the container :**

Note that I map the `server.port` of my *Spring Boot* `application.properties` file to the external port.

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -d myrepo/my-web-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

**docker container ls output :**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
3eff09347de3      myrep/my-web-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT              "catalina.sh run"        Less than a second ago            Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 8080/tcp    hardcore
```

**Error in the Browser :**

```
This site can’t be reached
```

**I am trying to access the URL using :**

```
http://192.168.99.100:8000/my-web-app/getResults
```

The same app works just fine when launched from Eclipse instead of a Docker container and I am able to access the rest end point using :

```
http://localhost:8000/my-web-app/getResults
```

---

**Update/Edit:**

I found the root cause. I need to map port **8000 to 8080** instead of mapping **8000 to 8000** itself :

```
docker run -p 8000:8080 -d myrepo/my-web-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

This means that the `server.port` property that I defined in my `application.properties` is not getting honored when starting up the container.

What is even more strange is that I can set the `server.port` to `8111` for example and still be able to access the URL if I use `-p 8000:8080`.

However, tomcat starts up on the port specified by `server.port` if I run the same application in Eclipse rather than a Docker container.

**Bottom line :** The `server.port` property defined in a *Spring Boot* application.properties file is not getting honored by the Docker engine.

Comment: Can you provide the output of cmd command `docker-machine ip` ?

Comment: @mslowiak the output is `192.168.99.100`. I have been able to access other apps in the past using this IP. It is this particular Spring Boot Java app that I am facing issues with.

Comment: Can you access your app under http://192.168.99.100:8000/my-web-app/getResults ?

Comment: @mslowiak No I can't as mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solution for standalone tomcat on docker image

`server.port` property is used to configure port for the spring boot embedded server. In your case you are trying to deploy a `war` file with your application to a standalone tomcat server (which is contained in your image) - so the embedded spring boot server is not even used and setting this property has no effect.

To achieve what you want you would have to modify the `server.xml` file of the tomcat that is installed on your image and modify the connector port. So you could copy the overriden `server.xml` to your image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">
    <!-- change port here-->
    <Connector port="8000" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

and the dockerfile :

```
FROM tomcat:9.0
EXPOSE 8000

COPY ./target/my-web-app.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war

#override server.xml
COPY server.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/

CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

and then run your image:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 -d myrepo/my-web-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

---

### Solution for spring boot jar with embedded tomcat running in docker container

If you have your spring boot jar copied to your image, you can set `SERVER_PORT` environment variable during container launching, to override the property defined in `application.properties` :

```
docker container run -e SERVER_PORT=8000 -p 8000:8000 myimage
```